# My bot discord doesn't work. I don't know why

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Why this code doesn't work?

```
client.on('message', message => {
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + ' stop'))
{
  channel.send('Resetting...')
  client.destroy()
  client.login("xxx");
}
})
```

I have this error :
[image]

Help me please

Comment: This code work :

`client.on('message', message => {
 if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + ' stop'))
 {
  if (message.author.id === 'xxx')
  {
   message.channel.send('Le bot redemarre....')
   client.destroy();
   client.login("xxx");
  }
 }
})
`

Answer (score 1):

Error says channel not defined. 
Assuming you want the bot to send the response to the same channel the command was called...
Try replacing the line
 `channel.send('Resetting...')` to `message.channel.send('Resetting...')`